# RewriteRule on local stack works, but not on server

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file with a basic rewrite rule wich works fine on my local stack, but it does not work on the shared server.

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content|wp-login/? - [L,R=404]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your server or shared server?

Comment: Most probably, your server has a *AllowOverride None* directive in the Apache configuration file. If you want to be able to use htaccess, you need to change it to *AllowOverride All*

Comment: Another possible reason is you don't have *mod_rewrite* active on the server.

Comment: @Luis Alberto Barandiaran thank you will check later and update.

Comment: "it does not work" - What happens exactly? What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file? And where have you placed this rule? Are there any other `.htaccess` files along the directory path? Is this a WordPress site? Are you using pretty permalinks?

Comment: Does not work, meaning does not redirect to default Apache Not Found page. Running Drupal and like to send spam bots to it, so the CMS does not get invoked when they probe my sites. Basic Drupal directives in the .htaccess file otherwise.

Comment: In that case, `AllowOverride None` is unlikely the issue, otherwise that would mean your Drupal site is not going to be working as intended, unless `index.php` is present in the URLs? (`AllowOverride None` disables the use of `.htaccess` completely - unlikely on a shared server, since you then can't use the popular CMS's - Drupal, WordPress, Joomla, etc. - properly.) What is important are the other points raised in my comment above, that you've not addressed. And what version of Apache are you using? Or are you on a LiteSpeed server?

Comment: "so the CMS does not get invoked when they probe my sites" - that will also depend on how the 404 `ErrorDocument` is configured, since this could also be configured to call the Drupal front-controller.

Comment: @MrWhite thanks.  Apache Version 2.4.57, no LiteSpeed server. No pretty permalinks. No other ' .htaccess'.  On my local stack (ddev) I can invoke the Apache default error page with the above rewrite rule. And my custom 404 page work for other errors, wich I want. I appreciate the pointers.

Comment: "No pretty permalinks." - In that case, maybe `.htaccess` files are not enabled after all (as mentioned above)?! If you put some "nonsense" at the top of the `.htaccess` file do you get an error? (Although risky to test on a live site as this _should_ "break" the site if `.htaccess` files are enabled.) "Does not work, meaning does not redirect to default Apache Not Found page." - So, what _does_ happen? Presumably you are getting a 404 of some kind? (If you are getting a Drupal 404 response then that would imply `.htaccess` is enabled!)

Comment: _Aside:_ `^wp-content|wp-login/?` - This regex is not doing what you think it's doing... It is matching `wp-content` at the start of the URL-path OR `wp-login` _anywhere_ in the URL-path (not necessarily at the start). The `^` (start-of-string anchor) is part of the first element of the regex alternation. The trailing `/?` is not really doing anything here.

Comment: Did test my development site with `.htaccess` "nonsense" in it and get Internal Server Error. Main site is hosted on same server. Yes, getting Drupal 404 response. Oh, I thought the regex would match anywhere in the url part by using `^wp-content|wp-login`. I am reading up on it, but still a bit lost here. Thanks again.